# android: add view to an inflated View

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I want to inflate a layout from my res/layout directory, and add some views to it in my activity class.

My layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_button"
        style="@style/simple_button"
        android:onClick="clickButton"
        android:text="@string/reg_button" />


    <!--  I WANT TO PUT CONTENT HERE ! -->

</LinearLayout>
```

In my java code, I try to inflate the above layout and add a linearLayout with a Button.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    //inflate xml
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)     LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.regions_search, null);


    //Create a new LinearLayout
    LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout(mContext);        
    newLinear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //create  a new Button
    Button test = new Button(mContext);
    test.setText("My button");

    //first , I add button to the LinearLayout
    newLinear.addView(test);

    //Then, I add layout to the inflated layout
    mainLayout.addView(newLinear);


    //display
    setContentView(mainLayout);
```

But the newLinear view (and its children) aren't getting displayed.

Comment: what you want? when you are press the `click button` then display `My Button`?

Comment: I just want to display MyButton when activity is called. ( In some cases, my button won't be displayed, that's why I want to control display in java side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your activity,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // display
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.regions_search);
    // Create a new LinearLayout
    LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    newLinear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // create a new Button
    Button test = new Button(mContext);
    test.setText("My button");

    // first , I add button to the LinearLayout
    newLinear.addView(test);

    // Then, I add layout to the inflated layout
    mainLayout.addView(newLinear);
}
```

And in your xml file (activity_main.xml)in write as shown below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/regions_search"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reg_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="clickButton"
    android:text="RegButton" />

<!-- I WANT TO PUT CONTENT HERE ! -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this it will work 100%.

Comment: In xml file LinearLayout Tag android:orientation="vertical" is most important first try by adding only this in layout. If it not works then try all this code.

Comment: Perfect ! I was persuaded that inflation was needed for this task. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the width and height parameters for both the new `LinearLayout` and the `Button` that you have added? Those parameters are required when creating views.

like this.

`newLinear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: Thank you. I try to add parameters for layout and button, but button is not displayed.

Comment: set the same for the button also.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thanks to Anil' code, I got my button displayed . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

test.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));

comment line

setContentView(mainLayout);

Comment: Thank you. If I comment "setContentView" code,  nothing appears on screen

Comment: try adding setLayoutParams with gravity to button

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've solved my issue with Anil' code. Thank you